# SQL query to get count and account details from another table

Tags: sql, count, left-join

I have these tables:

Song

id,album_id, name, audio_url

Album

id, title, description, account_id

Account

id, first_name, last_name, display_picture_url

Listening_Session

id, song_id, account_id

I want to be able to list popular songs as below:

Song ID | Song Name | First Name | Last Name | Display Picture URL | Session Count

Basically, I want to list songs with their author names and display picture as well as how many sessions were initiated to listen to the song (regardless author or other users listen to it), ordered by session count descending.

I tried:

```
SELECT s.*, pc.account_id, first_name, last_name, display_picture_url
FROM song as s
LEFT JOIN album a ON s.id = s.album_id
LEFT JOIN accounts acc ON acc.id = s.account_id
WHERE s.is_deleted = false AND s.id IN (
    SELECT s.id FROM song s
LEFT JOIN listening_sessions ls ON ls.song_id = s.id
WHERE s.is_deleted = false GROUP BY s.id
    ORDER BY count(s.id) DESC
    )
```

but i think I will lose the ORDER BY count as it is in the subquery and also not able to get the session count

I also tried:

```
SELECT s.*, COUNT(ls.id)
FROM song as s
LEFT JOIN listening_sessions ls ON ls.song_id = s.id
LEFT JOIN album a ON a.id = s.album_id
LEFT JOIN accounts acc ON acc.id = pc.account_id
GROUP BY s.id
ORDER BY count(ls.id) DESC
```

This will work but if I try to include first_name, last_name, and display_picture_url, it will say:

ERROR: column "acc.first_name" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function

EDIT: I implement primary keys in my table but not foreign keys for ease of use currently, idk if that makes a difference

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT TMP1.*, TMP2.account_id, TMP2.first_name, TMP2.last_name, TMP2.display_picture_url
FROM (
    SELECT s.*, COUNT(ls.id) AS Cnt
    FROM song as s
    LEFT JOIN listening_sessions ls ON ls.song_id = s.id
    LEFT JOIN album a ON a.id = s.album_id
    LEFT JOIN accounts acc ON acc.id = pc.account_id
    GROUP BY s.id
) TMP1
LEFT JOIN accounts TMP2 ON TMP1.account_id = TMP2.id
```

Answer (score 0):

I also tried:

```
SELECT s.*, COUNT(ls.id)
FROM song as s
LEFT JOIN listening_sessions ls ON ls.song_id = s.id
LEFT JOIN album a ON a.id = s.album_id
LEFT JOIN accounts acc ON acc.id = pc.account_id
GROUP BY s.id
ORDER BY count(ls.id) DESC
```

This will work but if I try to include first_name, last_name, and display_picture_url, it will say:

ERROR: column "acc.first_name" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function

This is because you're missing the new fields in the GROUP BY clause. You can fix it like this:

```
SELECT s.id,
       acc.first_name,
       acc.last_name,
       acc.display_picture_url,
       COUNT(ls.id)
FROM song AS s
LEFT JOIN listening_sessions ls ON ls.song_id = s.id
LEFT JOIN album a ON a.id = s.album_id
LEFT JOIN accounts acc ON acc.id = pc.account_id
GROUP BY s.id,
         acc.first_name,
         acc.last_name,
         acc.display_picture_url
ORDER BY COUNT(ls.id) DESC
```

Comment: yes, i know that but i wonder if its good to include them in group by, idk why it can be automatic... looking for a way that would be more logical but i would use this as last resort thx